# tee -a : No such file or Directory

Tags: bash, tee

Please have a look at following code.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG_FILE=/home/admin/scriptLogs.log
rm -f ${LOG_FILE}
echo "`date`:: Script Execution Started" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
DATABASE ACCESS CODE 2>&1
echo "`date`:: Script Execution Successful " | tee -a {$LOG_FILE}
exit 0
```

It produces following output:

```
> Tue Feb  7 12:14:49 IST 2017:: Script Execution Started 
> tee:{/home/admin/scriptLogs.log}: No such file or directory 
> Tue Feb  7 12:14:49 IST 2017:: Script Execution Successfull
```

However, the file is present in the specified location. It also gets appended with data except for the last echo statement. Why such behavior?

Comment: Just a typo - change `{$LOG_FILE}` to `${LOG_FILE}`.  Using `""` is even better.

Comment: By the way, the extra braces here are of no use, they do not help you in this context.  What might be more useful is double quotes, in case there is embedded whitespace in the path, for example: `tee -a "$LOG_FILE"`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to always quote your variables before expanding them to avoid reinterpretation (read about it here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)
Also, you should define LOG_FILE as a string (note the quotes below):

```
LOG_FILE="/home/admin/scriptLogs.log"
```

With that said, you have a typo in your script as mentioned by @codeforester

Also, you print that the execution was successful, without checking that it really was.

So you code should look like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    LOG_FILE="/home/admin/scriptLogs.log"
    rm -f "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "`date`:: Script Execution Started" | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
    DATABASE ACCESS CODE 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "`date`:: Script Execution Successful " | tee -a "$LOG_FILE"
    else
      ...
    exit 0
```

Note: I have removed the curly brackets, as they are not needed here (although it is not a mistake to do so)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @codeforester, use:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG_FILE=/home/admin/scriptLogs.log
rm -f ${LOG_FILE}
echo "`date`:: Script Execution Started" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
DATABASE ACCESS CODE 2>&1
echo "`date`:: Script Execution Successful " | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
exit 0
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case,I had defined a variable like:

```bash
LOG_FILE="~/test.log"
some_command | tee -a $LOG_FILE

tee: '~/test.log': No such file or directory
```

I learnt that "~" does not get expanded in double quotes.
The right way in this case would be

```bash
# Use absolute path
LOG_FILE="/path/to/home/test.log"

# OR

# Use $HOME environment variable
LOG_FILE="$HOME/test.log"
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question.

Comment: It is not totally unrelated. I faced exactly the same error as reported in the title, although due to a different reason.

Comment: And completely different to what's described in the body of the question.  You need to read more than just the title!

Comment: Dictionary [English]
obnoxious /əbˈnɒkʃəs/ adjective
extremely unpleasant.

Comment: Yes, I know that definition.  Not sure how that's relevant to this answer.