# tee command wont work with file name in a variable

Tags: bash, tee

I am trying to output the contents of a bash script into a file, but when i put the file name into a variable, it does not work. But if I hardcode the same filename, it works.

I tried this

```
{
echo "in the script"
file='file.txt'
} | tee -a "$file"
```

however I get the error `tee: : No such file or directory` I also echo "$file" and I get back file.txt, so I know the variable is getting set correctly.
when I do:

```
{
echo "in the script"
} | tee -a "file.txt"
```

it creates the file and fills it no problem. Why isn't my variable working here?

Edit: I am using brackets {} to encase my script because it is a rather large script that I want to output to a file. so `echo "in the script" | tee -a "$file"` will not work

Comment: Each command in a pipeline is executed in a separate subshell. The subshell that `tee` runs in cannot see any of the variables defined in the subshell running the code in braces. The variable must be defined _before_ you enter the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe that when you use the brackets to group commands it creates a context, and if you define variables inside it they will only exist in that context, therefore not being passed to the command after the pipe.</s>

My assumption was wrong as per the comments bellow, the reason this doesn't work is due to the pipe command executing both sides as independent sub-processes therefore variables defined on one side do not exist on the other.
Also on my suggestion bellow you might not want to use `&&` if you don't care about the result of the first command.

```bash
file="file.txt" && 
{
  echo "in the script"
} | tee -a "$file"
```

Comment: ahh yes that makes a lot of sense. I will see if I can build a solution around that. Thank you!

Comment: `{ }` just groups, and doesn't define a scope. I believe it's more to do with when the parts of a pipeline are evaluated; `str='abc' | declare -p str` is broken, too.

Comment: This is incorrect. Brackets don't create contexts, what's happening is that the pipe (`|`) forces the things on both sides of it to run in subprocesses; since the assignment happens in one subprocess, and the `tee` command runs in the other, the assignment has no effect on the `tee` command. Also, while this solution will work, using `&&` here is inappropriate, since that means "skip the second command if the first one fails". Just use a semicolon (or let the line break do the job).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="file.txt"
echo "in the script" | tee -a "$file"
```

It creates a file called `file.txt` with the contents `in the script`.

---

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086845/1766219

I'm not sure why you have the `{` and `}` in you code. If they are important, then please update your question with why you use them.

Comment: They are important, I updated the question. Thank you